# Sum of metrics over all Sonar projects ?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any way to aggregate metrics over all projects in Sonar ? For instance, is it possible to get the total number of SLOC ?

It seems that it should be a basic feature of Sonar.

I know about the Views plugin, but I'm looking for something free. And I don't need all the features of this plugin, only aggregates over all projects, not custom views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't been able to find anything, I have developed a very simple Sonar plugin that does the trick using the API provided by the Sonar server. Turned out to be pretty simple.

The plugin is available [here](https://github.com/wichtounet/aggregator-plugin), but it has been only tested on one Sonar instance.

[image: Global Metrics Widget]

Comment: For the popularize, you can write a message on [SonarQube Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) with a request to add it to [Update Center](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library).

Comment: @agabrys I'll have to check, but I believe they have a policy to not refer to plugin that has feature provided by one of their commercial plugins. I will post it on the forum at least :)